# Returning nil after string is made empty in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to write a piece of code that removes the first and last characters from a string. The characters need to be separated by spaces, rather than the given commas. e.g. ("1, 2, 3, 4") would be changed to ("2 3").

The bit I'm stuck on is - if I remove the first and last characters, and the string is now empty, it should return `nil` e.g. ("1, 2") would be `nil`.

So far I have:

```
def array(string)
 if string == ""
  return nil
 else 
  string.gsub!(',',' ')
  string.split
  string[2..-3]
 end
end
```

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
def array(string)
  string.gsub!(',',' ')
  split = string.split
  trimmed = split[1..-2].join(' ')
  if trimmed == ""
    return nil
  else
    return trimmed
  end
end

p array('1, 2, 3, 4') # "2 3"
p array('2, 3') # nil
```

A few issues with your code:

1. You were checking for an empty string at the *start* of your function instead of after you trimmed it. (So it would only return `nil` if you passed in exactly `""`.)
2. You weren't storing the results of the things you did. `string.split` doesn't change the value of `string`. It *returns* an array that's the result of splitting the string. So you need to store the result in an array. (E.g. `split = string.split`.) `string.gsub!(...)` is different. The exclamation mark means that it's a *destructive* operation. It actually changes the string.
3. Your indexes were wrong on your final trim, but that's probably because the split wasn't actually working, so you tried adjusting the indexes.
4. You never joined the results back up with spaces.

Here's another version for you to try:

```
def trim(string)
  trimmed = string.split(', ')[1..-2].join(' ')
  trimmed.empty? ? nil : trimmed
end
```

**EDIT**

It just occurred to me that maybe your indexes were right and you didn't intend to actually split at all... here's another working version of the code:

```
def array(string)
  string.gsub!(',', '') # NOTE: '' rather than ' '
  trimmed = string[2..-3]
  if trimmed == ""
    return nil
  else
    return trimmed
  end
end
```

Note that this version of the code relies on the comma-separated values being exactly one character long. It won't work if you pass in `'12, 35, 421'`. I'd stick to an approach based on `split` for that reason.

Comment: Thank you this is great, especially for explaining the issues with my code! Really helps me understanding it all better too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression in combination with the methods [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-count), [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-tr).

```
R = /
    \A            # match start of string
    .+?,\s+       # match >= 1 characters lazily (`?`) follow by a comma and >= 1 spaces
    \K            # forget everything matched so far
    .+            # match >= 1 characters greedily
    (?=,\s+\S+\z) # match a comma, >= 1 spaces, >= 1 characters other than
                  # sapces and end of string in a positive lookahead
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

def doit(str)
   str.count(',') <= 1 ? nil : str[R].tr(',', ' ')
end

doit "11, 12, 13, 14"
  #=> "12  13"

doit "1, 4"
  #=> nil

doit "1"
  #=> nil

doit ""
  #=> nil
```

The steps are as follows.

```
str = "11, 12, 13, 14" 
str.count(',') <= 1
  #=> false
s = str[R]
  #=> "12, 13" 
s.tr(',', ' ')
  #=> "12  13" 

str = "1, 4"
str.count(',') <= 1
  #=> true
nil
```

This regular expression would conventionally be written

```
/\A.+?,\s+\K.+(?=,\s+\S+\z)/
```

You could alternatively use a capture group in the regex instead of the two lookarounds:

```
R = /
   \A      # match start of string
   .+?,\s+ # match >= 1 characters lazily (`?`), a comma and >= 1 spaces
   (.+)    # match one or more characters (greedily) in capture group 1
   ,\s+\S+ # match a comma, >= 1 spaces, >= 1 characters other than spaces
   \z      # match end of string
   /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

and then

```
def doit(str)
  str.count(',') <= 1 ? nil : str[R,1].tr(',', ' ')
end
```

The choice is generally available. I prefer lookarounds or `\K`, but it's a personal preference.

Comment: Ruh roh. While clever, it's a little hard to read. I would have to think about it each time I came across it in source code. :-)

Comment: @JIm, a few points: 1) The question screamed "regular expression". 2) With practice, regex constructs such as positive lookbehinds and lookaheads become very natural and understood immediately. Once you know what `str[R]` returns the rest is obvious. 3) If you have to think about the solution, is that necessarily a bad thing? After all, it means that you are learning something that should make it easier to understand this and other regexes in future, as well as helping you use regexes to advantage in your own code.

Comment: This code has a syntax error (missing left paren, I believe), it returns strings like `"2  3"` (two spaces), and it doesn't return `nil` as the original question asked. And though it's an interesting approach, it's definitely not something I would recommend a beginner even try to read, let alone use.

Comment: If you want to take a regular expression approach (which I'd advise against), this should work: `str = str[/^[^,]+, (.*), [^,]+$/, 1].tr(',', ''); str.empty? ? nil : str`.

Comment: @smarx, thanks for pointing out where I was returning an empty space rather than `nil`, which I fixed. I also added a mention of using a capture group rather than the lookarounds. When you wish to anchor to the beginning and end of a string I thinks it's good practice to use `\A` and `\z`, even when the start and end of line anchors`, `^` and `$` will work because, as here, there is only one line.

Comment: This code still has the other issues I mentioned (extra space, error on `"1, 2, 34"`).

Comment: @smarz, I initially didn't understand what your  `"1, 2, 34"` was referring to because I had read "removes the first and last characters from a string" as "removes the first character and the last character from a string". My interpretation can't be right, however, as commas and whitespace are removed as well. I fixed that.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland -- all good points. If I became as fluent in regex as you (and I hope to) then I would not hesitate to use this. It certainly is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(str)
  return nil if str.count(',') <= 1
  str[(str.index(',')+1)...str.rindex(',')].lstrip.tr(',', ' ')
end
```

[String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-rindex) is use to find the index of the last comma in the string. The range is defined with three dots to exclude the last comma.

```
doit "1, 2, 3, 4" #=> "2  3"
doit "11, 12, 13" #=> "12"
doit "1, 4"       #=> nil
doit "1"          #=> nil
doit ""           #=> nil
```

Comment: Lol -- when it comes this syntax, I much prefer the single-line regex of your other answer.